# Qthread communication between threads (Python)

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

After reading the Qt docs over and over there's still one thing I'm not clear on.  In the following example, I'm emitting a signal in the worker thread to communicate back to the Ui thread and call a method.  My question is how to connect the objects to be able to communicate in the opposite direction.  I would like a condition in the Ui class to be able to emit a signal that the worker class can see and then do something with.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import time

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.show()

        #Clicking this button would tell the worker thread to do something
        self.guiButton.clicked.connect(Something goes here)


        self.startWorker()

    def startWorker(self):
        self.mainThread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.mainThread)
        self.mainThread.started.connect(self.worker.initWorker)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.mainThread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)

        #Connect the signal coming from the worker thread and call method
        self.worker.workerSignal.connect(self.workerSignalReceived)
        self.mainThread.finished.connect(self.mainThread.deleteLater)
        self.mainThread.start()

    def workerSignalReceived(self):
        print('signal received!!')


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    workerSignal = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.doSomeWork()

    def doSomeWork(self):
        #Emit every 1 second which will print to console each time
        #User presses gui button and loop breaks (which would end up finishing the thread)
        while True:
            self.workerSignal.emit()

            if signalFromUi: #This would be the signal coming from the Ui class.
                break

            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Depending on what you expect that "signal" should do, there could be different solutions. Please explain what are you trying to achieve and how does your thread work.

Comment: I've edited my original post to add a little more detail.  The guiButton would tell the worker thread to call a method (uiSignalReceived).

Comment: Sorry but that's not enough, how does the thread work? `doSomeWork` does nothing. Should it wait? Is there a loop? Are you using some external module that requires time for completion? Please, be more clear.

Comment: Sorry I'm not doing a good job explaining this.  I've tried to come up with an example with the same function as what I'm trying to do with my real code.  In this case, the worker thread would start and enter an infinite loop.  The only way to break the loop would be a user pressing a button on the GUI.